# BlackBerry VerticalFieldManager basics

Tags: blackberry

My app has a details screen like an AboutScreen. The height of all fields on the screen is more than the screen height, for all devices.  I need to place the elements in a VerticalFieldManager with scrolling.

In the sublayout method, what x and y coordinates are given so that I can place every field one after other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add the fields one after the other and enable scrolling, why would you override sublayout at all?

Instead just use new VerticalFieldManager mgr = VerticalFieldManager(Field.VERTICAL_SCROLL); and mgr.add(field1), mgr.add(field2), etc.

Alternatively, MainScreen defaults to using a VerticalFieldManager - so if your class extends MainScreen, ensure that your constructor calls super(VERTICAL_SCROLL); then you can just invoke ".add" directly.

Both cases will automatically handle vertical scrolling and offscreen placement.  If the fields are all labelfields, make sure to set them to "focusable" -- otherwise the  user won't be able to scroll.

Comment: Thanks Marc. But I want to place the fields in various positions on the screen.How can I place them with offscreen.

Comment: I haven't tried to do this yet myself, but I would think that you can set the absolute positions to offscreen values using layoutChild from within subLayout.  Unfortunately I don't know if the containing manager would automatically account for necessary scrolling, but it would seem logical.